# Many prototype for collection type

Tags: javascript, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, prototype

I'm on symfony and I use collection form to make a site to reserve tickets for a show.

The interface is simple, The user select the number of tickets he wants, then it display as much form prototype as tickets required. This part works well for me.

But I would like to display only 2 field ( name and surname ) not the age field ( It will be asked in another part of my form ) of my billet entity.

In the documentation they explain that you can display one field only (if I understand well ) :

```html
<ul class="billets" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.billets.vars.prototype.surname)|e }}">
```

Or the all entity fields :

```html
<ul class="billets" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.billets.vars.prototype)|e }}">
```

But not 2 fields, because when I try this, it display only the first field :

```html
<ul class="billets" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.billets.vars.prototype.name)|e }}">
  
   <ul class="billets" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.billets.vars.prototype.surname)|e }}">
```

Here is my billet type :

```html
class BilletType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('surname', TextType::class)
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('dateOfBirth', BirthdayType::class)
        ;
    }
}
```

[image: Here is what I want to get]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to avoid rendering fields I do it this way with option : `{'render_rest': false}) }`

```
{{ form_widget(edit_form._token) }}// mandatory but hidden
{{ form_end(edit_form, {'render_rest': false}) }} //closing the form
```

This way only fields specified in twig are rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create custom BilletType like this:

```
class CustomBilletType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('surname', TextType::class)
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
        ;
    }
}
```

Imbricate this CustomFormType in your main form:

```
 class BilletType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('billets', CollectionType::class, array(
                 'entry_type' => new CustomBilletType,
                 'allow_add' => true,
                 'allow_delete' => true,
                 'by_reference' => false, //use this for set dateOfBirth for all billet in your collection
             ))
             ->add('dateOfBirth', BirthdayType::class)  
         ;
    }
}
```

You will have your collection of billet with only dateOfBirth field.

For persist your dateOfBirth for all your billet, see in entity like this:

```
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->billets = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add billets
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Billet $billet
 * @return Billet
 */
public function addBillet(Billet $billet)
{
    $this->billets[] = $billet;
    $billet->setDateOfBirth($this->dateOfBirth); //Set the same date for all your billet
    return $this;
}
```

I hope I understand your problem..